# Family and CAF allowances in Lyon as a post-doctoral fellow

Tags: france, housing, benefits

I am going to Lyon in September with my (dependent) wife. I will join as a post-doctoral fellow in ENS-Lyon with salary more than 2000 Euro.

I have chosen an accommodation that is eligible to receive CAF benefits. I would like to know if I am eligible to receive CAF benefits.

Any website or resources that highlight the eligibility criteria to receive CAF benefits would be helpful. If yes, then is it possible to estimate the amount of CAF benefit that I might be eligible to receive?

Comment: Are you speaking about _Aide personnalisée au logement_ (APL) ? https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F12006

Comment: There's a simulator here (in French) : https://wwwd.caf.fr/wps/portal/caffr/aidesetservices/lesservicesenligne/estimervosdroits/lelogement/#/stateaccueil